# locale does not work at first request in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

There are 3 controllers. Index controller , View Controller, LanguageController. LanguageController - A from with a dropdown displaying header than can be viewed in Index and view.

I have dumped locale in the controller and LocaleSubscriber.
Whenever i change the dropdown value , the locale value in the controller is changing ,but not the LocaleSubscriber one.The value in the LocaleSubscriber is only changing in the second request

consider a dropdown with values a,b,c.

For the first dropdown change to a, controller locale will dump a. For the second drop down change to b, controller will change to b and  LocaleSubscriber will change to a.

How can i get the currect value of locale in LocaleSubscriber on drpdown change?

Language Controller:

```
$languageForm = $this->createForm(SelectLanguageForm::class,$languageEntity,array('languagecode' => $formattedLanguageData));
$languageForm->handleRequest($this->get('request_stack')->getMasterRequest());
$request->getSession()->set('_locale',$languageForm->getData()->getlanguageCode());
var_dump($languageForm->getData()->getlanguageCode() .'locale in controller');

//debug_print_backtrace();
return $this->render('partials/header.html.twig', [
            'languageForm' =>  $languageForm->createView(),
        ]);
```

LanguageForm:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $languageChoices = $options['languagecode'];
        $builder
            ->add('languagecode', ChoiceType::class, ['choices' => $languageChoices,'label' => 'Select Language',
                ])
            ->getForm();

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     * @return null
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'languagecode' => false,
        ]);
    }
```

LocaleSubscriber

```
public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }


        $locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale');

        var_dump($locale.'  subsciber locale');
        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }

    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [['onKernelRequest', 20]],
        ];
    }
```

EDIT:
In the LanguageController values of

```
 $request->attributes->get('_locale')
```

and

```
$request->getSession()->get('_locale')
```

are differnt.

If I add a refresh page  (header("Refresh:0");) when attributes locale and session locale are differnt. It will work as expected.But this is not a good solution.